# Why sql tables are out of UTF-8 on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, utf-8

I have a xls file that contains Persian characters and I want to load it and save it to an existing database.

I have tried this to load the file:

```
Dim str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
```

But now when I load it and save it to database Persian characters looks like a `?` sign.

But the question is this:

When I load it in local or save some thing into the database from local there is no problem and all is OK but after publishing it to the server not only the rows imported from the xls file looks bad but also when I save some thing from a control like a textbox to the database the UTF-8 characters are like `?` this too.

Is not the sql tables on Unicode by default?!

What is wrong here?

**Update**

This is how I save the loaded datas in database:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(str)
con.Open()
Dim ds As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", con)
Dim dt As New DataTable()
ds.Fill(dt)
Dim sqlconnection As SqlConnection
Dim sqlcommand As String
Dim sqlconnectionsrting As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IEEConnectionString").ConnectionString
sqlconnection = New SqlConnection(sqlconnectionsrting)
sqlconnection.Open()
code = (Convert.ToInt32(dt(i).Item(9))).ToString()
Dim productType = (Convert.ToInt32(dt(i).Item(11))).ToString()
Dim name = dt(i).Item(10)
Dim date1 = DateAndTime.Now
Dim price = (Convert.ToInt32(dt(i).Item(8))).ToString()
Dim factory = dt(i).Item(7)
Dim type = dt(i).Item(6).ToString()
Dim clearance = dt(i).Item(5).ToString()
Dim weight = dt(i).Item(4).ToString()
Dim perimeter = dt(i).Item(3).ToString()
Dim dimension = dt(i).Item(2).ToString()
Dim lenght = dt(i).Item(1).ToString()
Dim thickness = dt(i).Item(0).ToString()
sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductType,Name,Date,Code,Price,Factory,Type,Clearance,Weight,Perimeter,Dimension,Length,Thickness,IsShown) VALUES ('" + productType + "','" + name + "','" + date1 + "','" + code + "','" + price + "','" + factory + "','" + type + "','" + clearance + "','" + weight + "','" + perimeter + "','" + dimension + "','" + lenght + "','" + thickness + "','false')"
Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqlcommand, sqlconnection)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Comment: The codepage used by SQL server is configurable and from my limited experience is UTF8.

Comment: The database have been created before in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS and I just added some tables to it and now the new tables don't support UTF-8 when publishing it to server(It is OK in local).

Comment: What **datatype** are your column in the database table? To support Unicode, you **must** use `NVARCHAR(x)` - `VARCHAR` does **not** support Unicode or UTF-8 ..

Comment: Check the datatype of the column where you store your data, `varchar` or `char` will not work.

Comment: They are all nvarchar(x)!

Comment: OK, so how are you storing those values into the SQL Server database after you've loaded them from the Excel sheet? Can you share some relevant code?

Comment: OK.I Updated the question with saving codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sqlcommand is wrong. You have to use Parameters instead of plain text command, because it vulnerable. Or you have to quote ALL values!

SQL Server treats 'some string' as VARCHAR and casts it to NVARCHAR when inserting. You have to write N'some string' for NVARCHAR. But I strongly recommend you to use parameters!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Dim str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";
```